# Intellij 'cannot resolve' error in drools file

Tags: java, drools

```
public class Record{
      String name;
      String firstname;
      String lastname;
}
```

```
import Record;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
dialect  "mvel"
rule "check"
    when
        record : Record(!StringUtils.isEmpty(name)
        && (firstname.equalsIgnoreCase("John") || lastname.equalsIgnoreCase("Doe")))
    then
        System.out.println("JohnDoe");

end
```

equalsIgnoreCase is in red wavy underline, Intellij cannot resolve the symbol, it doesn't recognize the method in java.lang.String

```
rule "checkagain"
    when
        record : Record(!StringUtils.isEmpty(name)
        && (firstname.contains("John") || lastname.contains("Doe")))
    then
        System.out.println(record.name);

end
```

in this rule, the intellij would mark the first record `record unexpected` with redlines, `contains` cannot find declaration go to, the second record says cannot resolve symbol

Comment: Anyone have idea why is it? I am able to run though, even with redlines

Comment: I don't see any declaration of firstname. maybe it's not what you think it is

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post the Record class definition. It's all going to hinge upon how `firstname` is declared.

Comment: Or it could be a bug with intelliJ's parsing of the rule file. You're not really doing 'best practice' rules so it could be getting confused. I found that while the Drools library was pretty lenient with what it let you get away with, IntelliJ really tried to force you to best practices.

Comment: Thank you, I just updated. I would be looking for the 'best practise' rules, is there any reference you could give?

Comment: The drools documentation would be my first start tbh.